# Usar tema Dashboard Bootstrap com React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Sou novo no React js e gostaria de saber como eu poderia usar um tema de dashboard bootstrap que usa imports locais dos arquivos de css e js localizados na pasta "assets" do projeto.

Tentei colocando os imports no index.html do projeto no head e no final da tag body nas paginas js usei o plugin para converter o html em jsx e na versão desktop funcionou normal porem na mobile o menu n abre, gostaria se saber a maneira ideal de fazer isso, tem algum tutorial?

Obs.: usando cdn eu consegui porem esse tema usa seus próprios arquivos de importação. segue meu index.html do projeto e estrutura de pastas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">

    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/datatables/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Responsive datatable examples -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <!-- App css -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  
    <!-- jQuery  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/waves.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/plugins/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/pages/jquery.hospital_dashboard.init.js"></script>

    <!-- App js -->
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria utilizar alguma solução construída com React, como [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) (v3 e v4) ou [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) (v4). Misturar componentes "não React" e jQuery com componentes React - e provavelmente outras tecnologias do ecossistema React - é uma péssima ideia.

Answer (score 0):

Cara uma solução boa seria usar um pacote chamado **styled-components**, ele é um pacote que te da a liberdade para criar componentes react com seu estilo css, eu acho uma ideia muito boa, além de você conseguir dividir e reutilizar seus componentes você ainda pode usar css + js passando propriedades dinâmicas nas tags e etc... Segue exemplo da sintax:

```
const Button = styled.a`
  /* This renders the buttons above... Edit me! */
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 11rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;

  /* The GitHub button is a primary button
   * edit this to target it specifically! */
  ${props => props.primary && css`
    background: white;
    color: palevioletred;
  `}
`
```

https://styled-components.com/

Comment: Outra solução validar é instalar o pacote do bootstrap pelo seu gerenciador de pacotes (npm install --save bootstrap), e depois importá-lo  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' em src/index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Luan Mário

Boa tarde. 
Não é uma boa ideia misturar tecnologias como jQuery e React. Isso irá trazer malefícios para a organização e legibilidade do projeto. O legal do React é o seu ecossistema de diversas libs que trazem agilidade e ajudam a manter padrões dentro do projeto.

Um alternativa que recomendo é o  react-bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction/).
Ou outro UI que preferir. Assim acredito que teu projeto possa ficar dentro de boas práticas com React.